# Generic Table<TEntity>

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql, entity

Trying to use Linq to SQL for a small project I'm working on at home. I have generated a the context code and all my entity classes using dbmetal.exe (from the DBLinq project) against a local MySQL database.

Everything is working great, but I'm trying to abstract some redundant code and I'm running into issues trying to do so.

Basically all my entities are of type `Table<TEntity>` in my context class. For example I have `Table<User>` and `Table<Calendar>`.

While I was architecting the various interfaces for the repository behaviors I realized that there some methods that were very redundant with each entity. For example the ID field:

```
User findById(int id);
Calendar findById(int id);
```

I designed my tables so they all have 3 fields in common [ID, DATECREATED, DATEUPDATED]. Since those fields are common I wanted to have a common behavior instead of rewriting those methods for each entity.

So I made my repository classes (UserRepository, CalendarRepository) inherit a common "Repository" class that's defined like that:

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected MyContext context;

    private DbLinq.Data.Linq.Table<T> currentTable;

    protected Repository() {
        context = new MyContext();

        Type currentType = this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        currentTable = //Set currentTable based on currentType. e.g.: currentTable = context.User;
    }        

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public T findById(int? id)
    {
        return currentTable.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ID == id);
    }

    public T findByDateCreated(DateTime dateCreated)
    {
        return currentTable.SingleOrDefault(d => DateTime.Equals(dateCreated, d.DateCreated));
    }

    public T findByDateUpdated(DateTime dateUpdated)
    {
        return currentTable.SingleOrDefault(d => DateTime.Equals(dateUpdated, d.DateUpdated));
    }

    public T insert(T domainObject)
    {
        currentTable.InsertOnSubmit(domainObject);
        return domainObject;
    }

    public T save(T domainObject)
    {
        context.SubmitChanges();
        return domainObject;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (context != null)
            context.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Well it turns out this is more difficult than I thought. When I try to set:

```
currentTable = (Table<T>)context.User;
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert type 'DbLinq.Data.Linq.Table<Models.Domain.User>' to 'DbLinq.Data.Linq.Table<T>'
```

Implicit casting does not work either.

Anyone has ever done something similar successfully? That'd be very sad if I had to have all my Repository classes implement the same findById method with exactly the same code in it... I'm sure there is a way to NOT do that, I just can't find it. :)

Comment: is it failing at compile time or at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That'd be very sad if I had to have
>   all my Repository classes implement
>   the same findById method with exactly
>   the same code in it

The code isn't exactly the same.  In each case, you are referring to a different table in your context.

I understand your logic; you want to be DRY. But the reason you have a repository is to give you the capability to abstract your data access logic away by injecting a mock repository instead of your real repository to facilitate unit testing.  The most practical (and flexible) way to do this is to keep your tables (and your DAL objects) separate and distinct.  By attempting to genericize part of your DAL objects, you are introducing additional coupling which will complicate your unit testing.

Comment: True the referenced objects are different but the code is identical. But I do get the Unit testing perspective... IOC was actually one of my next step using Ninject. Thanks for your help Robert.

Comment: @Robert is Unit Testing still that important, even if i have 5 tables with exactly the same methods? And what if i'd like to sacrifice Unit testing for more DRYness, how can i do it? I struggled with the same problem as Lancelot 3 days ago and still can't create a generic structure to accept all my Log tables.

Comment: @AdrianoRR: To clarify, the purpose of a repository is to abstract away your data persistence.  This can be done to facilitate unit testing, or make it possible to replace the underlying data store with a different vendor.  In practice, unit testing merely serves to confirm that the repository methods return the correct records, and swapping out the data store hardly ever happens.

Comment: @Robert I see. Well, I'm willing to let go of unit testing on this case. So far, I've been modifying my db.dbml so it can support my DRYness (actually a super class). However, manipulating the dbml itself doesn't seem a good practice, that's why when I saw this post I was very excited, but no aswers were given to Lacelot's problem, just your clarification.

Comment: @AdrianoRR: Lancelot's approach is an anti-pattern anyway.  At some point you have to put a name to whatever you are retrieving, so you might as well name it in your repository method, i.e. `public Customer GetCustomer(int id)`.  Trying to do it in a single method by passing a type parameter just pushes the complexity somewhere else.

Comment: @Robert Didn't know it was an anti-pattern 'solution'. So i guess if i have 50 different tables, but 5 of them behaves exactly the same way i should still create 50 different DAL classes (repository) right? In the end, i end up having to name my repositories methods, so i guess you were right all the time.

Comment: @AdrianoRR: If 5 tables behave exactly the same way, it's better to have a single table with an additional field that distinguishes each record between the 5 different variants.